# Where is the yuicompressor.jar file?

Tags: jar, installation, yui-compressor

I just downloaded the yuicompressor-master from https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor and am planning on using it in my symfony2 app. The problem is that there is no yuicompressor.jar file.

I am guessing I need to build the .jar file from the files in the yuicompressor-master folder but after some time duckduckgo'in around (i try and avoid google) I can't find instructions on how I am supposed to build the .jar if that's what needs to be done.

I am comfortable on the command line and don't mind reading through some man documents to figure this out. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I apologize if this is a dumb question, I have no experience working with java obviously. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran these commands from terminal to install the yui compressor:

Mac osx:

```
brew install yuicompressor
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/yuicompressor/2.4.7/libexec/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar ~/htdocs/symfony/app/Resources/java/
```

ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install yui-compressor
```

Anyway, would still like to know what to do with the files from https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor

Comment: Any guide for Windows users?